# Date a year from now and check what is the next Term from that Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this Table which contains **Term** and **TermStartDate** and **TermEndDate**. I have to consider **Todays date** and then check in which term that falls under(Current Term) and then Consider a Date exactly 360 days from the TermEndDate of Current term(Calculated_Date).

Once I get that Date I have to check which Term Falls After that date.Basically what is the TermStartdate that falls after the Calculated_Date.

Note:

Basically, I need all the records of the students who fall between current term and exactly a year before the Current term. say for example, if this term is Fall 2013 , I would need records from Spring 2013. Should not consider Fall 2012.

**Edit:**

Sample Table

```
  Term           TermStartDate    TermEndDate
 Fall 2012          2012/08/27     2012/12/15
 Spring 2013        2013/01/14     2013/04/26
 Sumr I 2013        2013/05/06     2013/06/29
 Sumr II 2013       2013/07/01     2013/08/24
 Fall 2013          2013/08/26     2013/12/14 
 Spring 2014        2014/01/13     2014/04/26
```

Step 1: GetDate()

Step 2: Check the TermEndDate falling just after the GetDate() (Gives the Current term)

Step 3: Calculate the date exactly 360 days before the Current Term End Date

Step 4: The First Term That Falls after the date that is Calcuted in Step 3

Comment: Sample data and desired results instead of word problem, please

Comment: So to clarify, you want the first term with a start date after a date parameter you provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the problem, but as you requested, try this:

```
DECLARE @terms TABLE(term varchar(50),termStartDate date, termEndDate date)
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES('Fall 2012','8/27/2012','12/15/2012')
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES('Spring 2013','1/14/2013','4/26/2013')
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES('Sumr I 2013','5/6/2013','6/29/2013')
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES('Sumr II 2013','7/1/2013','8/24/2013')
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES('Fall 2013','8/26/2013','12/14/2013')
INSERT INTO @terms VALUES('Spring 2014','1/13/2014','4/26/2014')

DECLARE @today date =GETDATE()
SELECT @today = termEndDate 
    FROM @terms 
    WHERE termStartDate<=@today AND termEndDate>=@today
SELECT term 
    FROM @terms 
    WHERE termStartDate>=DATEADD(d,-360,@today) AND termStartDate<=GETDATE()
```

This will list all terms included in the period 360 days prior to the end of the current term.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT min(termStartDate)startDate FROM (
    SELECT termStartDate 
        FROM @terms 
        GROUP BY termStartDate 
        HAVING termStartDate>=DATEADD(d,-360,@today) 
               AND termStartDate<=GETDATE()
)z
```

will get the startDate for the earliest term.

Comment: Davids, the above solution almost works but "WHERE termStartDate>=DATEADD(d,-360,@today) AND termStartDate<=GETDATE()" gives us 4 terms, but we want the First term in these 4 terms. Is there a way we can do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @lastTermEnd

SELECT @lastTermEnd=DATEADD(d,-360,TermEndDate)
FROM Students
where GETDATE() between TermStartDate and TermEndDate

SELECT TOP 1 *
from Students
WHERE TermStartDate between @lastTermEnd and GETDATE()
ORDER BY TermStartDate
```

This will list first term which fall after the calculated date.

UPDATE:

```
DECLARE @lastTermEnd datetime
DECLARE @TermEnd datetime

SELECT @TermEnd=TermEndDate
FROM Students
where GETDATE() between TermStartDate and TermEndDate

SET @lastTermEnd=DATEADD(d,-360,@TermEnd)

SELECT TOP 1 TermStartDate,@TermEnd
from Students
WHERE TermStartDate between @lastTermEnd and GETDATE()
ORDER BY TermStartDate
```

Comment: dcp1986: Can you tell me how can we get the the first termEndDate which >=GetDate(). Within the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this I think is what you're asking but I'm actually not entirely sure. Your question is very difficult to follow.

```
SELECT *
FROM myStudents
WHERE theDate BETWEEN DATEADD(yy,-1,currentTerm) AND currentTerm
```